# Delete rows in one table based on values in THREE columns of another table

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks - one of demand and one of storage. My purpose is to delete a number of tools from the demand workbook based on the quantity, type and configuration in the storage workbook. The deleted tools need to be those whose due date is closest to the current date.

For example, if I have 2 tools of type Aleris 8500 in the storage workbook, I delete the first 2 upcoming Aleris 8500 tools in the demand workbook.
Until now I did this based solely on the tool type. Now I want to add a second criterion - the tool's configuration. I need help with this as I'm a beginner in VBA.

To continue the previous example, if the 2 tools of Aleris 8500 have a configuration of 150, I need to delete the first 2 upcoming Aleris 8500 tools with this configuration.

The Demand workbook looks like this:

[image]

The Storage workbook looks like this:

[image]

Here is my code that deletes just based on tool type:

```
Sub Demand_Minus_Storage()
  Dim QT As Long
  Dim i As Long

'open demand workbook
  Dim Demand_WB As Workbook
  Set Demand_WB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rosipov\Desktop\eliran\MFG - GSS\Demand_Optics " & Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yyyy") & ".xlsx")

'open storage workbook
  Dim storage_wb As Workbook
  Set storage_wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rosipov\Desktop\eliran\MFG - GSS\OpticLabStorage.xlsm")




'now we romove from the demand what we already have in our storage


'Illuminators
Dim rngRow As Range

Demand_WB.Worksheets("Illuminators").Activate


  With storage_wb.Worksheets("Illuminator")
    For Each rngRow In .Range(.Rows(3), .Rows(WorksheetFunction.Match("*", .Range("A:A"), -1))).Rows
      With Worksheets("Illuminators").UsedRange.Offset(1)
        .Sort .Columns(5)
        .Offset(-1).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=" & rngRow.Cells(1) & "*"
        .Sort .Columns(2)
        With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Areas(1)
          Range(.Rows(1), .Rows(WorksheetFunction.Min(rngRow.Cells(3), .Rows.Count))).Delete
        End With
        .Offset(-1).AutoFilter
        .Sort .Columns(2)
      End With
    Next
  End With
  Cells(1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Just to ensure this, what you want to delete also has the "Due Date" as empty? Or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: No, i want to delete first those that their due date is the closest. those who has no Due date I want last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**   <sup><sub>(v0.1.1)  Bug fix to avoid deleting a tool when the quantity is zero.</sub></sup>

To add the second criterion, all you need is an extra sort and an extra autofilter.

The following is your original code with the modifications added:

```
Sub Demand_Minus_Storage()
  'Dim QT As Long
  'Dim i As Long

'open demand workbook
  Dim Demand_WB As Workbook
  Set Demand_WB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rosipov\Desktop\eliran\MFG - GSS\Demand_Optics " & Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yyyy") & ".xlsx")

'open storage workbook
  Dim storage_wb As Workbook
  Set storage_wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rosipov\Desktop\eliran\MFG - GSS\OpticLabStorage.xlsm")




'now we romove from the demand what we already have in our storage


'Illuminators
Dim rngRow As Range

Demand_WB.Worksheets("Illuminators").Activate


  With storage_wb.Worksheets("Illuminator")
    For Each rngRow In .Range(.Rows(3), .Rows(WorksheetFunction.Match("*", .Range("A:A"), -1))).Rows
      If rngRow.Cells(3) > 0 Then
        With Demand_WB.Worksheets("Illuminators").UsedRange.Offset(1)
          .Sort .Columns(6) ' BBSE
          .Sort .Columns(5) ' Tool Type
          .Offset(-1).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=" & rngRow.Cells(1)
          .Offset(-1).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="=" & rngRow.Cells(2)
          .Sort .Columns(2) ' Due Date
          With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Areas(1)
            Range(.Rows(1), .Rows(WorksheetFunction.Min(rngRow.Cells(3), .Rows.Count))).Delete
          End With
          .Offset(-1).AutoFilter
          .Sort .Columns(2) ' Due Date
        End With
      End If
    Next
  End With
  Cells(1).Select

End Sub
```

I've also added a tidied and fully documented version:

```
Sub Demand_Minus_Storage()

  Const n_DemandHeaderRows As Long = 1
  Const i_SN_UTID   As Long = 1
  Const i_Due_Date  As Long = 2
  Const i_Tool_Type As Long = 5
  Const i_BBSE      As Long = 6
  Const n_StorageHeaderRows As Long = 2
  Const i_OpticLab_Tool_Type     As Long = 1
  Const i_OpticLab_Configuration As Long = 2
  Const i_OpticLab_QT            As Long = 3

  Dim ƒ As WorksheetFunction: Set ƒ = WorksheetFunction

  Dim storage_wb As Workbook
  Set storage_wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rosipov\Desktop\eliran\MFG - GSS\OpticLabStorage.xlsm")

  Dim Demand_WB As Workbook
  Set Demand_WB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rosipov\Desktop\eliran\MFG - GSS\Demand_Optics " & Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yyyy") & ".xlsx")

  With storage_wb.Worksheets("Illuminator")
    ' Use the worksheet function "Match" to find the last storage used row
    ' Then loop through each storage row
    Dim rngRow As Range
    For Each rngRow In .Range(.Rows(n_StorageHeaderRows + 1), .Rows(ƒ.Match("*", .Columns(i_SN_UTID), -1))).Rows
      ' Only action tools with a quantity greater than zero
      If rngRow.Cells(i_OpticLab_QT) > 0 Then
        ' Skip the header rows and at the same time add at least one row after the end of the table
        With Demand_WB.Worksheets("Illuminators").UsedRange.Offset(n_DemandHeaderRows)
          ' Need to sort by BBSE and by tool type so the rows to be deleted are contiguous
          .Sort .Columns(i_BBSE)
          .Sort .Columns(i_Tool_Type)
          ' Back up to last header row and apply the filter
          ' Filter for the tool type that matches the tool type in the current storage row
          .Offset(-1).AutoFilter Field:=i_Tool_Type, Criteria1:="=" & rngRow.Cells(i_OpticLab_Tool_Type)
          ' Filter for the BBSE that matches the configuration in the current storage row
          .Offset(-1).AutoFilter Field:=i_BBSE, Criteria1:="=" & rngRow.Cells(i_OpticLab_Configuration)
          ' Need to re-sort by date as we previously sorted by tool type
          .Sort .Columns(i_Due_Date)
          ' Grab the first visible contiguous area. There is always at least the one from the row(s) after the end of the table.
          ' If there are any matching tools, these will form an area preceding the end of table area.
          With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Areas(1)
            ' Make sure we don't delete more rows than were actually found.
            ' If none were found, empty rows at the end of the table get deleted.
            Range(.Rows(1), .Rows(ƒ.Min(rngRow.Cells(i_OpticLab_QT), .Rows.Count))).Delete
          End With
          ' Turn autofilter off and show all hidden rows
          .Offset(-n_DemandHeaderRows).AutoFilter
          ' Need to re-sort by date as hidden rows were not sorted in previous date sort
          .Sort .Columns(i_Due_Date)
        End With
      End If
    Next
  End With
  ' Tidy up
  Cells(1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: hey, when I in storage 0, it steel delets rows, you have an idea how to handle?

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Oops! There was a bug in the original code I posted in the previous question that you used for this question. I've updated this answer with the fixed versions

Comment: IT WORKS WELL, NO BUGS AND NOTHING. THANK YOU.